# Can you add prefix to namespaces that ReSharper's "Adjust Namespaces" generates?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resharper

I'm working on a Unity/C# project where none of the files have namespaces. I like the idea of not having to manually add namespaces, and I like the idea of namespaces (somewhat) matching the folder structure. However, at the moment, using ReSharper's `Adjust Namespaces` causes namespaces of the type `Game`, `Network`, etc, which can obviously cause problems with other namespaces.

Is it possible to somehow tell ReSharper to use a prefix (e.g. "projectname.", "companyname.", "com.company.project.", etc) for the randomly generated prefixes? Or do we actually have to put all the files in anther folder just to get this structure (a bit like what you'd do in Java, I guess)?

Comment: ReSharper uses the project's default namespace as prefix to the folder names. Maybe it's enough for you to set this default name space and use "adjust namespaces" again? (right click project -> properties -> default namespace).

Comment: Yes. Perfect! 
Edit: I've added that it's a Unity project. With Unity projects, you don't have access to change the project properties, unless you to to Tools for Unity and allow access, but this isn't recommendable. Instead you should set the default namespace in the Unity project settings: `Edit > Project Settings > Editor > Root namespace`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ReSharper uses the project's default namespace as prefix to the folder names.

So maybe it's enough for you to set this default namespace to your desired prefix and use "Adjust Namespaces" again.

To set the default namespace:

- right click on the project item in the project explorer
- choose "Properties..."
- on the project's property page, choose "Application" on the top left
- set "Default namespace" to your desired prefix

---

In Unity projects you'll have to set the "root namespace" in the Unity projects settings (as OP pointed out himself):

```
Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor -> Root namespace
```

Comment: Sorry, even better, could you let people know that if they are working on a Unity project (like I am), they should set the root namescape in Unity project settings instead, as Unity would otherwise overwrite the change ;)

Comment: @SvendHansen added it. I have no experience in Unity, so I trust you that the information is correct :)